# How to do some trigonometric derivations

Tags: trigonometry

Two substitutions fail, so do I forget some earlier  steps?

For

`Cos[x] == Sin[(1/2)*Pi + x] /. x -> (1/2)*x` = true

I don't get the final answer, but only true.

`Cos[(1/2)*x] == Sin[(1/2)*Pi + (1/2)*x]`   (final answer)

A second derivation case :

`Sin[x] == 2*Cos[x/2]*Sin[x/2] /.  Cos[(1/2)*x] -> Sin[(1/2)*Pi + (1/2)*x]`  (*no substition possible *)

Comment: Look at the output of `Trace[Cos[x] == Sin[(1/2)*Pi + x] /. x -> (1/2)*x]`. Note that the initial equation evaluates to `True` before the replacement ever comes into play.

Comment: Thanks, Trace shows the initial equation evaluates to True before the replacement , so no need to come up for MMA with a another evaluation then.
How this list exactly works i don't know yet.
Is it not possible to force MMA to evaluate only the replacement ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you want to know about `Trace`; highlight it in Mathematica and press `F1` for help.

Comment: Thanks, can imagine that my question is not understandable.
Evalueting the expression is not a good idea seems, so with command  Inactive you can prevent that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Inactive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html)

```
Inactive@(Cos[x] == Sin[(1/2)*Pi + x]) /. x -> (1/2)*x
```

> [image: trig1]

```
Sin[x] == 2*Cos[x/2]*Sin[x/2] /. 
 Cos[(1/2)*x] -> Inactive@Sin[(1/2)*Pi + (1/2)*x]
```

> [image: trig2]

Comment: thanks . There is a reason behind it , why "inactive" command is used.
What is that reason?

Comment: @janhardo in a notebook try to run `Sin[(1/2)*Pi + (1/2)*x]` and `Inactive@Sin[(1/2)*Pi + (1/2)*x]`. You will see that Mathematica makes the first `Cos[x/2]` automatically -no `Factor`, `Simplify`, `Reduce` etc. The other remains as it is; it is `Inactive`. You can always `Activate` the expression at the end and get a `True` statement

Comment: thanks, i do see the difference

Comment: @janhardo glad I was  able to help